# Sending custom URL in e-mail after Stripe payment

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe payments in the website where **the key task is to send e-mail with custom generated URL to the customer after the payment**.

The website runs on Wordpress and from my first research there is several ways how to implement it: payment link / WooCommerce / one of WP plugins. So far I am open for all of them, however I am not sure which one could be the best for the intended task mentioned above.

I have zero experience with Stripe, so I would be grateful for some advice on how to accomplish that task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PaymentLink, or Stripe Checkout is similar products, but they create link *for making payment*. You mentioned you want a link *after the payment*, which sounds like a receipt? If that is the case, take a look at [their receipt guide](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts).

Comment: No no, the link I am talking about has nothing to do with payment itself. The whole idea is to sell digital product which will be available on unique link. So what I am searching for is the way how to proceed the payment and after that to send the email to the customer, where that unique link will be included... Is it maybe possible to include it into receipt content then?

Comment: It sounds like Stripe's PaymentLink product would be what you need. It includes pre-generated link for you to include in any email:
https://stripe.com/en-jp/payments/payment-links

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Maybe I was not able to explain it correctly, but what I am searching for is really sending custom e-mail AFTER the payment... Maybe it could be done by customizing the receipt as you mentioned, but according to the guide it seems I can only change basic things like branding or languages, while I would also like to add the unique link into the content... Is that possible? Or maybe there is another way how to send email after the payment (where I can put whatever I want)?

Answer (score 0):

Both [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and [Easy Digital Downloads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/) implement this, so I recommend using them alongside Stripe.

Here's a screenshot of a WooCommerce purchase receipt. The download link is shown in red. WooCommerce generates a unique download link when a customer purchases a downloadable item.

[image: WooCommerce purchase reciept]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However what I need is: 1) Use an URL which I am creating by my own PHP script (because of special parameters) 2) Link to the website, not a file... Is that possible by WooCommerce or the second mentioned plugin too?